# Vector to dataframe with variable row length

Tags: r

Given a vector, I want to convert it to a dataframe using a 'key' value which is randomly distributed throughout the vector at the start of what is to be a row. In this case, "z" would be the first value in each column.

```
vd <- c("z","a","b","c","z","a","b","c","z","a","b","c","d")
```

The resultant data should look like:

```
#using magrittr
data.frame(x1 = c("z","a","b","c", NA), x2 = c("z","a","b","c", NA), x3 = c("z","a","b","c","d")) 
%>% transpose()
```

One solution would be to find the largest distance between 'keys' in the vector and then interject blank values at the end of 'sections' that are smaller than the longest 'section' so you could use `matrix()`

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `key`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. In your question title, you ask for 'vector to matrix' but then you say that you want to convert 'it to a data frame'... Also, your code produces a very unreadable data frame. Just as an advice I would name my columns and also use NA instead of ""

Comment: @smanski I guess the OP means 'z' in his example. This is how the vector is divided. Is this correct,  OP ? Your question is somewhat unclear here and a test of our logic

Comment: @WC RN NR-DA (interesting name) : Are you sure you want to use `transpose` on your data.frame? This returns a list

Comment: read.table(text=gsub ("z","\n",paste(vd,collapse=" ")),fill=T)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
plyr::ldply(split(vd, cumsum(vd == "z")), rbind)[-1]
```

(copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498439/convert-rows-into-columns-by-matching-string-in-r))

result:

```
  1 2 3 4    5
1 z a b c <NA>
2 z a b c <NA>
3 z a b c    d
```

Comment: nice catch finding this other question

Comment: you should add the library call

Comment: I was honestly surprised to see this - the other question was asked earlier today, and at first I thought it's the same person asking their question twice...

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cumsum` to identify groups then split them. Then we append the vectors and format them as a `data.frame`.

```
x <- split(vd,cumsum("z"==vd))
maxl <- max(lengths(x))
as.data.frame(lapply(x,function(y) c(y,rep(NA,maxl-length(y)))))
#     X1   X2 X3
# 1    z    z  z
# 2    a    a  a
# 3    b    b  b
# 4    c    c  c
# 5 <NA> <NA>  d
```